# How to Create a Python dictionary with multiple values from a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a Python list like below:

```
['Phylum_C3.30', 'CDgu97FdFT6pyfQWZmquhFtiKrL1yp', 'pAnstdjgs3Dzzc8I0fOLERPeXNZIuT_legend', 'pAnstdjgs3Dzzc8I0fOLERPeXNZIuT', 'Family_E3.30', 'iKUmlH47RuphW3NbqXykn0ayizhztF', 'ZzTzTLMDCHIkPBo9waDG3lBZi6u2hG_legend', 'ZzTzTLMDCHIkPBo9waDG3lBZi6u2hG', 'Class_C2.60', 'D0RRB3F0dCl39KuEZNqfdD8q9jKzUu', 'MYe9hzd8BTeg1OW00TMQQ0qc60KWIH_legend', 'MYe9hzd8BTeg1OW00TMQQ0qc60KWIH']
```

I wish to have a dictionary where keys would be any element that starts with 'Pylum' or 'Class' or 'Order' or 'Family' or 'Genus' and values will all values following that element until the next element with 'Pylum' or 'Class' or 'Order' or 'Family' or 'Genus'.

For e.g:

The final dictionary will look like:

```
{
    "Phylum_C3.30": [
        'CDgu97FdFT6pyfQWZmquhFtiKrL1yp',
        'pAnstdjgs3Dzzc8I0fOLERPeXNZIuT_legend', 
        'pAnstdjgs3Dzzc8I0fOLERPeXNZIuT'
    ], 
    "Family_E3.30": [
        'iKUmlH47RuphW3NbqXykn0ayizhztF',
        'ZzTzTLMDCHIkPBo9waDG3lBZi6u2hG_legend',
        'ZzTzTLMDCHIkPBo9waDG3lBZi6u2hG'
    ],
    "Class_C2.60": [
        'D0RRB3F0dCl39KuEZNqfdD8q9jKzUu',
        'MYe9hzd8BTeg1OW00TMQQ0qc60KWIH_legend',
        'MYe9hzd8BTeg1OW00TMQQ0qc60KWIH'
    ],
}
```

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Python. Did you want to create a dictionary with *lists* as the values perhaps? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop over the list, and if a value tests as a key store that as the most 'recent' key seen, and add a list to the dictionary for that key. Then for all other non-key values add to the list associated with the last-seen key:

```
prefixes = ('Pylum', 'Class', 'Order', 'Family', 'Genus')
output = {}
current_key = None
for elem in inputlist:
    if any(elem.startswith(p) for p in prefixes):
        # this is a key, add it to the output
        current_key = elem
        if current_key not in output:
            output[current_key] = []
    else:
        output[current_key].append(elem)
```

You can tweak the way a key is handled a bit; dropping the `if current_key not in output` would result in duplicate entries overwriting previous entries. Or you could raise an exception for the `if current_key in output` case if duplicate entries is supposed to be a bug.

Comment: Looks good to me. My only suggestion would be to perhaps check if `current_key` is still `None` in the case the first element is not a valid key, but you could probably forego this if you trust the input. It would just result in a dictionary with a `None` key in it, not a huge deal.

Comment: @CurtisLusmore: because not having a key as the first element would be a bug, not checking gives us a free exception for that case. It would *not* result in a dictionary with `None` as a key; you get a `KeyError` instead